# Show and hide on click jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have 3 anchor tags and on click I want to show a div further down the page. And then I want to hide the current div (the one that is shown further down the page) if another anchor tag is clicked. So far my code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.text-show-1').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.container-show-1').removeClass('hide');
});
```

text-show-1 is what is being clicked on, container-show-1 is what is being shown on click.

I tried my own if statement inside the statement and it came out like this - but this didn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.text-show-1').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.container-show-1').removeClass('hide');
    if ($('.text-show-2').on('click', function () {
            $('.container-show-1').addClass('hide');
        }))
    if else($('.text-show-3').on('click', function () {
            $('.container-show-1').addClass('hide');
        }))
});
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: jquery has inbuilt `hide` and `show` functions. Why not use them instead? You could alternatively use `toggle`

Comment: Ill give it a go, cheers

Comment: What do u mean by `this doesn't work`. Plz explain or better yet, create a jsfiddle / plunker so that ppl can reproduce the issue.

Comment: figured it out guys. thanks for all your help. Cheers. 3 on click functions

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use `.show()`, `.hide()`, or `.toggle()` is up to you. Read [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) to decide.

In terms of functionality, don't nest click events inside other click events. They will never run since they could only possibly run if you clicked on the first element, but you can't be simultaneously clicking on two elements --see what I'm saying?

Have three separate click events which each result in different actions:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.text-show-1').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.container-show-1').show();
  });

 $('.text-show-2').on('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('.container-show-1').hide();
     //should you also be showing other things?
 });

  $('.text-show-3').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     $('.container-show-1').hide();
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery

TO hide the element use `$(".container-show-1").hide();`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.text-show-1').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.container-show-1').show();
});
$('.text-show-2').on('click', function () {
            $('.container-show-1').hide();
        });
$('.text-show-3').on('click', function () {
            $('.container-show-1').hide();
        });
});
```

Not sure if this is what you are expecting to see.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("button").click(function(){ $("div").hide(1000); });
```

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is easier to manage by giving the similar elements a common class and/or `data-` attribute so that you can select them all at once and assign a single generic event handler. The event handler then just needs some way to know which div relates to the clicked item. One way to do that is to give each anchor a `data-` attribute that specifies the `id` or `class` of the associated div.

So maybe a little something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Hide all of the divs initially:
  $('.associated').addClass('hide');
  
  // When any anchor with the data- attribute is clicked:
  $('a[data-associated]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Hide any div currently showing:
    $('.associated').addClass('hide');
    // Unhide the div associated with the clicked item by using the
    // value from the anchor's data- attribute:
    $('#associated-' + $(this).attr("data-associated")).removeClass('hide');
  });
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#associated-1" data-associated="1">Show 1</a>
<a href="#associated-2" data-associated="2">Show 2</a>
<a href="#associated-3" data-associated="3">Show 3</a>

<div class="associated" id="associated-1">Content One</div>
<div class="associated" id="associated-2">Content Two</div>
<div class="associated" id="associated-3">Content Three</div>
```

Note: I have given each div a unique `id`. You could use a unique `class`, but identifying unique items is what `id` is for. Also, I've set the `href` of the anchors to the `id` of the associated divs - this is completely optional and not related to the hide/show behaviour, but it means if the user has disabled JavaScript clicking the anchors will jump to those divs as part of standard anchor behaviour.)